# von Neumann entropy - calculation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy

How to calculate von Neumann entropy in continious case?

Consider density matrix elements:

$$ \rho(x,x') $$

Then:
$$S = -Tr(\rho \log \rho) = -\int \rho(x,x')\log \rho(x',x)dx'dx $$ 
Is it true?

Comment: No, this is deeply flawed. The logarithm of a matrix is not the logarithm of the matrix element you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My last answer was wrong on the final equation. I've corrected it below.

Not really. Remember the definition of the trace, it's the sum of the *diagonal* matrix elements, not all of them. Using a discrete basis $\{|e_i \rangle\}_{i=1}^\infty$, the trace of an operator $\hat A \in \mathcal{L(H)}$ can be written as:
$$\mathrm{Tr}(\hat A) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \langle e_i | \hat A | e_i \rangle$$

For a continuous basis $\{|x \rangle \}_{x\in \mathcal D}$, the analogous equation is:
$$\mathrm{Tr}(\hat A) = \int_{\mathcal D} dx \ \langle x | \hat A | x \rangle$$

where $\mathcal{D}$ is the relevant integration domain, e.g. $\mathcal D = \mathbb R$.

So the correct equation would be:
$$S = -\mathrm{Tr}(\hat\rho \log \hat\rho) = - \int_{\mathcal{D}} dx \ \langle x | \hat\rho \log \hat\rho |x \rangle \qquad (*)
$$
Now if $\hat \rho$ is diagonal in the $\{|x \rangle\}_{x \in \mathcal D}$ basis, so would $\log \hat \rho$, meaning that:

$$S = - \int_{\mathcal{D}} dx \ \langle x | \hat\rho \log \hat\rho |x \rangle = - \int_{\mathcal{D}} dx \ \langle x | \hat\rho |x \rangle \langle x | \log \hat\rho |x \rangle \qquad (**)$$

$$S= -\int_{\mathcal D} dx \ \rho(x) \log \rho(x)$$

with $\rho(x)$ being the diagonal elements $\rho(x) \equiv \langle x | \hat \rho | x \rangle$.

If $\{|x \rangle\}_{x \in \mathcal D}$ is not an eigenbasis of $\hat \rho$, writing a general equation in terms of the matrix elements $\langle x | \hat \rho |x' \rangle = \rho(x,x')$ is going to be difficult. This is because writing the matrix elements of $\log \hat \rho$ in terms of those of $\hat \rho$ is hard in general. You would need to actually calculate the matrix logarithm first, which generally is:
$$\log \hat \rho = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} (\mathbb{\hat{I}} - \hat \rho)^n$$

So for a general case, using $(*)$, you can formally write $S$ as:

$$S =- \int_{\mathcal{D}} dx \ \langle x | \hat\rho \log \hat\rho |x \rangle = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{\mathcal D} dx \langle x | \ \hat \rho (\mathbb{\hat{I}} - \hat \rho)^n \ | x\rangle$$

Note however that since the trace is basis independent, it usually makes much more sense to first find the spectrum of $\hat \rho$, and calculate the entropy in that basis instead using $(*)$.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need an infinity of integrals.

That is, whereas 
$$S = \operatorname{Tr}\rho  \rho =  \int \rho(x,x')  \rho(x',x)dx'dx ,$$
you are looking at 
$$S = -\operatorname{Tr}(\rho \log \rho) = \operatorname{Tr}\left ( \rho  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1\!\! 1 -\rho)^n ~/n  \right  ), $$ 
which necessitates an integral per matrix multiplication. Note the sign of the  [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series).